# Changing Database name on the go php

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have a master database that has all the other database names, when a user logs in i find the appropraite database name on this master database and then use that name to connect the user to the system.What i do is, after getting the database name i save it as a session and pass that session to the database name for my other database conncetion.  This is how i connect the user to the system

```
class DataDB extends mysqli {

// single instance of self shared among all instances
private static $instance = null;
// db connection config vars
private $dbName = $_SESSION['dname'];
private $dbHost = "localhost";

//This method must be static, and must return an instance of the object if the object
//does not already exist.
public static function getInstance() {
    if (!self::$instance instanceof self) {
        self::$instance = new self;
    }
    return self::$instance;
}
```

so far its refusing to work am getting this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_SESSION' (T_VARIABLE). Also is there a better way to do this without session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the way you assign the private property by setting it in the `__construct()` method of your class.

Although I do not recommend this, use a config file, you could use this [Symphony component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config.html) though. Here you have an [example](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html).

Also a quick tutorial for using [composer](https://www.codementor.io/php/tutorial/composer-install-php-dependency-manager) might aid you

EDIT:

```
private function __construct() {
    $this->dbName = $_SESSION['dname'];
    parent::__construct($this->dbHost, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->dbName); //or pass it directly
}
```

Comment: this how i assign it  `parent::__construct($this->dbHost, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->dbName);`

Comment: I have the implementation

Comment: it works, thanks. Taking a look at config. my problem with that is how to change the data of the config file like how i did here with sessions

Comment: Check out the example, you need to define a class `DatabaseConfiguration ` and instantiate it in your database construct method and get values (you have examples of parsing. Or just include a `constants.php` to have access in every point within your app and use them.

Comment: I would also use a dependency injection module tu pass these values in the construct. check out https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html